# Earth Orbits a K-Type Star. What Would the Visual Scenery Look Like?

Tags: earth-like, stars, day-night, alternate-earth

To clarify on the title, K-type main-sequence stars--shortened as "orange dwarves"--are subjects of excitement for astronomers and astrobiologists.

Why?

1. They emit enough radiation to provide a high-enough temperature to make water liquid but not high enough for solar radiation.  (This would mean no auroras, but it also means no genes would be damaged by UV exposure.)
2. They have a longer lifespan than G-type stars.  (15-30 billion years compared to our sun's total of ten billion.)  This means that life would be given more time to evolve.
3. They are three to four times more common than G-type stars, making the search for Earth-like exoplanets hypothetically easier.
4. Despite having 45-80% of a G-type star's mass, they can still be just as bright.

Now let's throw Earth into this scenario.  It still orbits this orange sun at a distance of 93 million miles.  To narrow the scenario even further, this question focuses on the emphasis that a star has on color.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

These photos are of the hours of the day, from dawn to dusk under a blue atmosphere and a yellow star.  Now imagine Earth still having its blue atmosphere but the star now being orange instead of yellow.  To the human eye, would this change the color of any part of the day in any way?

Comment: I think you'd find this interesting: www.solstation.com/images/star3sky.jpg I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for though. Like the range of colors for the whole day? I think whether or not there are moons or how bright they are will affect this, and if you are looking for ranges, knowing the atmospheric composition of your planet would help guide answers in the right direction. This question is actually pretty close to being answerable; it just needs a bit more information

Comment: "Despite having 45-80% of a G-type star's mass, they can still be just as bright." No, they are less bright, your planet needs to be closer to compensate for this.

Comment: @Vincent  That's not what this article says:  https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn17084-orange-stars-are-just-right-for-life/

Comment: @Pleiades  One--I can't click on the link.  Two--the first question is the right answer.

Comment: Well the article is misleading since the difference is pretty significant. A very bright K star is 60 % of the Sun brightness.

Comment: To the human eye your K-type star is still a blinding ball of white in the sky.  The sky's color would really be defined by the atmosphere and weather.  A human compatible world would seem likely to have a similar range of atmospheric colors as Earth does.

Comment: @Vincent  You have any evidence to back this statement up?

Comment: Outside of Wikipedia, I haven't done a more specific research . Just look the Harvard stellar classification.

Comment: The atmosphere is blue due to [Rayleigh Scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) caused by our parent star. Should said star be a K-type Orange Dwarf, the colour of our sky would shift towards red (This is due to the lower amounts of Blue/Violet light being emitted by a K-type star). Thus, as viewed from Earth; the appearance of the sky would be paler blue/white and the star would be closer to an orange colour in the sky.

Comment: Also a K-type dwarf is less massive and thus has less solar output. This means that any planet that needs to be in the "Habitable Zone" for liquid water to exist on its surface would need to be closer to the parent star than Earth is to our current star. More importantly [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitability_of_K-type_main-sequence_star_systems) explains all.

Comment: I suggest you check out a YouTube channel called "Artifexian". He has a lot of stuff on building stars and planets as well as worldbuilding in general.

Comment: @Raisus  So which color would the sky be?  Red, or pale blue?

Comment: @JohnWDailey - pale blue. Closer to white, certainly not the Azure colour we currently have

Answer (score 1):

All colors would undergo a subtle change. On Earth, daytime color temperature is assumed to be 5500K or higher. For a smaller K-type star, everything would seem like it is illuminated by a "Cool White" (3500K – 4100K) light bulb. Not as yellowish as Incandescent/Soft White (2700K – 3000K) light, but still a very perceptible difference.

Comment: I'm actually not sure it would be noticeable unless you could do a direct comparison switching back and forth between suns. Most people see a 4000K LED as bluish, but it's actually yellower than daylight which most people would call yellowish.  Some of that's doubtless due to the blue sky, but I think it's mostly because our eyes are not designed to see absolute differences very well.

Comment: People would totally adapt to it, no problem. However, color temperature can play real tricks with our eyes, and something like [Black and blue or white and gold dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress) can happen.

Comment: @Alexander  While I don't doubt your answer, I can't imagine what it'd look like visually.

Comment: @JohnWDailey this is actually very easy. All colors will look like it's a couple of hours later in the afternoon (or earlier in the morning), with the sunset and sunrise being particularly reddish.